# Set Similarity measure with known item similarities and abundances

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, discrete-mathematics

I'm looking for a similarity measure (like the Jaccard Index) but I want to use known similarities between objects within the set, and weigh the connections by the item abundances. These known similarities are scores between 0 and 1, 1 indicating an exact match.

For example, consider two sets:
SET1 {A,B,C} and SET2 {A',B',C'}

I know that
{A,A'}, {B,B'}, {C,C'} each have an item similarity of 0.9. Hence, I would expect the similarity of SET1 and SET2 to be relatively high.

Another example would be: consider two sets SET1 {**A**,B,C} and SET2 {**A**,B',C',D,E,F,.....,Z}. Although the matches between the first three items are higher than in the first example, this score should likely be lower because of the size difference (as in Jaccard).

One more issue here is how to use abundances as weights, but I've got no idea as how to solve this.

In general, I need a normalized set similarity measure that takes into account this item similarity and abundancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I guess you need **clustering error** as similarity measure. It is the proportion of points which are clustered differently in A' and A after an optimal matching of clusters.  In other words, it is the
scaled sum of the non-diagonal elements of the confusion matrix, minimized
over all possible permutations of rows and columns. It uses the Hungarian algorithm to avoid high computational cost and it penalizes different number of elements in sets.

Comment: Quick follow-up: what would you be clustering here? Any literature I can read up on? Note that items can appear in more than one set.

Comment: Usually when you are working with unsupervised learning (clustering) the output from your model is a set of labels and you need to match these predicted labels with the correct ones (ground truth). If the ground truth is [A, A , B] and the model's output is [1,1,2], it means the CE is 0 and your model is robust enough.

Comment: There's nothing related to clustering itself, it's just applied to it as a similarity measure. If you have more than a pair of sets you can combine the CE of each set combination. Search for: Methods for Comparing Subspace Clusterings by Anne Patrikainen [http://cis.legacy.ics.tkk.fi/annep/lisuri.pdf]

Comment: Through this reference you might be able to even find other evaluation measures (perhaps more useful than CE), such as Rand Index and Adjusted Rand Index.

Comment: Interesting stuff! Thank you very much, I'll be sure to look into this.